# Overflow issue in Excel VBA script / large list creation

Tags: excel, vba

I need to write a list of new part number descriptions for uploading. There are several lists, the first list is ~600,000 numbers. The parts are basically a block with height, width, depth dimensions.

Considering it has 3 dimensions/vectors to it, I thought it **can't** be easily formatted into one column with VBA. Maybe I am wrong and there is an easier way.

```
For DEPTH = MIN_D To MAX_D Step STEP_D
    For WIDTH = MIN_W To MAX_W Step STEP_W
        For HEIGHT = MIN_H To MAX_H Step STEP_H
            ROW = ROW + 1
            Cells(ROW, COLUMN).Value = BLOCK & "-" & HEIGHT & "-" & WIDTH & "-" & DEPTH
        Next HEIGHT
    Next WIDTH
Next DEPTH
```

The code works (ROW is Long, other dims are Integer) for 200,000 iterations (181x101x11 HxWxD), but I am unsure about it working beyond this.

So if there are 600000+ steps, is there a better way to do it? Like maybe pre-allocating the space or using waits etc?

Comment: If you are writing that much data to the worksheet, you should consider writing it to an array first, then writing the array to the worksheet all at once. Also, you should just go ahead and declare everything as type `Long`.

Comment: For uploading to what/where?  Are you really just writing a single column of data?  That doesn't seem like it would be very useful...

Answer (score 0):

Create an array that you can loop through, and once the loop has finished, set a range object to match the array's dimensions and proceed to write the array to the worksheet.

*Untested:*

```
Dim DEPTH As Long, MIN_D As Long, MAX_D As Long, STEP_D As Long
Dim WIDTH As Long, MIN_W As Long, MAX_W As Long, STEP_W As Long
Dim HEIGHT As Long, MIN_H As Long, MAX_H As Long, STEP_H As Long
Dim COLUMN As Long

' . . .

Dim wsArr As Variant
ReDim wsArr(roundUp((MAX_D - MIN_D) / STEP_D) * roundUp((MAX_W - MIN_W) / STEP_W) * _
            roundUp((MAX_H - MIN_H) / STEP_H) + 3, 1)
For DEPTH = MIN_D To MAX_D Step STEP_D
    For WIDTH = MIN_W To MAX_W Step STEP_W
        For HEIGHT = MIN_H To MAX_H Step STEP_H
            wsArr(Row, 1) = BLOCK & "-" & HEIGHT & "-" & WIDTH & "-" & DEPTH
            Row = Row + 1
        Next HEIGHT
    Next WIDTH
Next DEPTH

Dim rng As Range
With ActiveSheet
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, COLUMN), .Cells(UBound(wsArr) + 1, COLUMN))
End With

rng.Value = wsArr
```

```
Function roundUp(ByVal dVal As Double) As Long
    If Int(dVal) = dVal Then
        roundUp = dVal
    Else
        roundUp = Int(dVal) + 1
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

As a somewhat quicker alternative, you can use Power Query.

Add your parameters to a table:

```
+-------+-------+--------+-------+-------+--------+-------+-------+--------+
| MIN_D | MAX_D | STEP_D | MIN_W | MAX_W | STEP_W | MIN_H | MAX_H | STEP_H |
+-------+-------+--------+-------+-------+--------+-------+-------+--------+
|     1 |    11 |      1 |     1 |   101 |      1 |     1 |   181 |      1 |
+-------+-------+--------+-------+-------+--------+-------+-------+--------+
```

Now add a query:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Change Type Numbers" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each {_, Int64.Type})),
    ListDepth = List.Numbers(#"Change Type Numbers"[MIN_D]{0},(#"Change Type Numbers"[MAX_D]{0}-#"Change Type Numbers"[MIN_D]{0})/#"Change Type Numbers"[STEP_D]{0}+1,#"Change Type Numbers"[STEP_D]{0}),
    ListWidth = List.Numbers(#"Change Type Numbers"[MIN_W]{0},(#"Change Type Numbers"[MAX_W]{0}-#"Change Type Numbers"[MIN_W]{0})/#"Change Type Numbers"[STEP_W]{0}+1,#"Change Type Numbers"[STEP_W]{0}),
    ListHeight = List.Numbers(#"Change Type Numbers"[MIN_H]{0},(#"Change Type Numbers"[MAX_H]{0}-#"Change Type Numbers"[MIN_H]{0})/#"Change Type Numbers"[STEP_H]{0}+1,#"Change Type Numbers"[STEP_H]{0}),
    #"Make Table" = Table.FromList(ListDepth,Splitter.SplitByNothing(),{"Depth"}),
    #"Add Width" = Table.AddColumn(#"Make Table", "Width", each ListWidth),
    #"Expand Width" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Add Width", "Width"),
    #"Add Height" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expand Width", "Height", each ListHeight),
    #"Expanded Height" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Add Height", "Height"),
    #"Change Type Text" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Height",List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(#"Expanded Height"), each {_, type text})),
    #"Added Output" = Table.AddColumn(#"Change Type Text", "Output", each Text.Combine({"BLOCK",[Height],[Width],[Depth]}," - "), type text),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Output",{"Output"})
in
    #"Removed Other Columns"
```